# Android Distribution Restricted Certificate

Tags: android, certificate, aide-ide

I'm using AIDE (The Android IDE) on my tablet to develop Android applications. I paid the $25 developer fee and went to submit my free app in today (Made in HTMl5/Cordova/PhoneGap), and well I got this error.
[image]

Any help on how to solve this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you generate your own production signing key and supply that to AIDE? If AIDE does not generating a production signing key, or does not support signing apps with custom keys, you will need to do those steps on a more traditional development environment, or use a service like PhoneGap Build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to create your own key store. To do this, open the menu, click `More` > `Export Apk`.

Then select `Create Key store` and follow the steps - just make sure that the validity is more than 30 years. Click `Create`

Then click `Export Apk` again. Click Export and type in the password for your key store. Click `OK`. You have now exported your app! **DO NOT DELETE YOUR KEYSTORE** you will need it to update your app. Infact I would recommend backing it up.

Comment: I had to purchase the full version of AIDE in order to do that. Thanks very much bro.

Comment: No problem - I was surprised myself when there weren't any easy to find tutorials for AIDE keystore creation and publishing on Google.

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate a developer `private` digital `signing key` .You can use standard tools — `Keytool` and `Jarsigner` — to generate keys and sign your application .apk files

I would suggest you to read this link completely if you have not done
    http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html